# Отображение WriteableBitmap в PictureBox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Всем доброго времени суток
Переношу проект WPF на WF и не могу никак разобраться с WriteableBitmap и отображением его на форме. Возникла проблема с этим участком кода

```
private void SetupBitmap()
    {
        _wb = new WriteableBitmap(
            _width,
            _height,
            96,
            96,
            PixelFormats.Bgra32,
            null);

        PaintSurface.Source = _wb;
    }
```

PaintSurface - это Image Name="PaintSurface"

В WinForms пробовал пойти таким путём...

```
private void SetupBitmap()
    {
        _wb = new WriteableBitmap(
            _width,
            _height,
            96,
            96,
            PixelFormats.Bgra32,
            null);

        PaintSurface.Image = BitmapFromWriteableBitmap(_wb);
    }

    private Bitmap BitmapFromWriteableBitmap(WriteableBitmap writeBmp)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;
        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)writeBmp));
            enc.Save(outStream);
            bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

... где в этом случае PaintSurface это picturebox

В итоге получил черный pictureBox.
Можете мне помочь все таки как-то вывести изображение в pictureBox, или какой-то другой контрол, чтобы он в лайве обновлялся, в этом собственно и суть writeablebitmap

Comment: @aepot `Переношу проект WPF на WF`, то есть, у человека идет обратное (что оооочень удивительно и странно).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ой :), я настолько удивлен, что неправильно прочитал. Очень удивительно и странно. Быть может не пользоваля привязками и командами, и погиб в войне с контролами. Других объяснений у меня нет. Штож, удачи автору тогда в это нелегком труде.

Comment: Может быть, идиотские бизнес-требования. WinForms, ADO.NET и прямое использование потоков. Бывает.

Comment: @VladD я бы таким требовальщикам Rx.NET в код подмешал. :)

Comment: @aepot: И pattern-matching, побольше. Ну если нету async/await, то без Rx на самом деле никак.

Comment: @VladD ну за 3.5 я бы под дулом гранатомета не стал браться. :)

Comment: Решил не портить себе нервы и добавить просто контрол Image с WPF и закинул его в элемент хост.

Comment: Но теперь проблемка с ивентом MouseMove, т.к элемент хост такой ивент не обрабатывает. Есть предложения?

Comment: @PineappleHaze: Положить сверху другой контрол? (А кстати, что это за хост такой?)

Comment: @VladD Да, так и сделал. Создал в солюшене с формами User Control WPF Library, в разметке просто добавил Image, на форму закинул ElementHost и в списке который выпадает после добавления Element Host выбрал проект wpf, который был создан. А ну еще не забываем что перед тем как добавлять в Element Host, нужно сбилдить wpf проект

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Зачем вам вообще понадобился ElementHost? Зачем вам использовать ненативный контрол в WPF?

Comment: @VladD Если честно не знаю что такое "ненативный контрол в WPF", решил пойти таким путём, ибо нашел только такой вариант, ещё и работает так как надо. Сложно или нет - не знаю, чтобы сделать это я потратил от силы минуты 2.

Comment: Например, убрать зависимость от WinForms из проекта полностью, и пользоваться нативным WPF-овским `Image`